# image comparison with cv2.matchShapes()

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm pretty new to **Digital Image Processing** and I'm trying to find all similar images in a directory to a given one using the **cv2.matchShapes()**

This is the code I use

```
def search(query_image_path):
    query_image = cv2.imread(query_image_path, 0)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(query_image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    c1, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cnt1 = max(c1, key=cv2.contourArea)

    for img in images:
        image = cv2.imread("database//" + img, 0)
        ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        c2, h2 = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        cnt2 = max(c2, key=cv2.contourArea)

        similarity = cv2.matchShapes(cnt1, cnt2, 1, 0.0)
        if similarity < 0.1:
            similar_images.append(image)
    return similar_images
```

Here is a [photo of the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijqEv.png) matchShapes() returns:

now the problem is that it finds this [this two photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhXsr.jpg) as similar

and some photos that are more similar it doesn't find them as similar.

I think the problem is that I am comparing wrong contours. I've tried it without

```
cnt2 = max(c2, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

using only

```
cnt2 = c2[0]
```

but it was worse and it was then when i realised that I'm probably comparing different contours, so I've printed all the contours and saw that most of them are just tiny dots and the contour that i need is sometimes in 2nd sometimes in 36th place etc.
That's why i tried with max but that doesn't help either.

I don't know how to find the right contour since it's in different position in all the photos.

Comment: as you've found out yourself, there are a lot of hard problems to solve until you can use a function like matchShapes and still downt know whether that function will work well in rhe end. I would suggest to manually segment some of your images. Mark the the wanted contour either with polygon drawing like  labelMe or by drawing a mask with for example GIMP or controlling the background during capturung and try usage of matchShapes more focused.

Comment: for automatic segmentation of the leaf you could try otsu thresholding or superpixel segmentation, but dont expect perfect results. make sure to test every single step.